Unable to detect Bluetooth in IoT Gateway - No default controller available
We have purchased a IoT Gateway (DSGW-210 Dusun) to enable connecting IoT enabled health devices connect to it through Bluetooth and send telemetry to a server in Azure. The device supports Bluetooth 5.2, however the documentation for this device leaves a lot to be desired. I was hoping to try a sample project to test Bluetooth but I don't seem to be able to detect the Bluetooth.
I tried command 'bluetoothctl devices' and I get "No default controller available".
I have tried reboot and reset of the Gateway, but to no avail.
I can open a admin website when connected to the Gateway. This website lists bluetooth devices nearby, so I know there is Bluetooth and its able to scan for devices.
Any help on how to detect and use Bluetooth would be appreciated. Thanks.

The quickstart guide talks about a BLE test tool: https://wiki.dusuniot.com/iot-gateway-hardware/dsgw-210-rk3328-gateway/quick-start-guide#83--ble Have you tried that?

Yeah. Saw that. Only they talk about downloading it from some FTP site and I don't see any FTP site link in that page.

Might be this one: https://github.com/dusuniot/Dusun_BLE_Code_Sample

Yeah. Trying that one. Been a long time since I did C programming so taking time fixing bugs in that sample. and making it work. But was hoping if there are some other methods that can at least detect the Bluetooth. bluetoothctl, hciconfig, etc are not detecting the Bluetooth. Not sure if its because the board is not Raspberry Pi or because the Bluetooth chip is on board rather than connected as a peripheral.
